# How do I get the HoloViews box selection tool to synchronize multiple connected plots?

Tags: python, holoviews

How do I get the HoloViews box selection tool to synchronize multiple connected plots?

For example, with

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import holoviews as hv

from holoviews import opts 

hv.extension('bokeh')

def scatter_hist(src, x, y):
    p = hv.Scatter(src, x, y).hist(num_bins=20, dimension=[x, y]).opts(
            opts.Scatter(show_title=False, tools=['hover','box_select']), 
            opts.Histogram(tools=['hover','box_select']),
            opts.Layout(shared_axes=True, shared_datasource=True, merge_tools=True)
        )
    return p

scatter_hist(ds, 'x', 'y')
```

I can get `box_zoom` to work as expected (zooming in any one of the three figures imposes the corresponding zoom on the other two) but `box_select` does not behave in this way. I can only box-select in the top histogram (though the toolbar doesn't highlight the tool), and this has no effect on the other plots.

[image]

I've experimented with different values for `tools` (including omission) for both `opts.Scatter` and `opts.Histogram` but can't discern any pattern with what's going in when I do (in fact I'm a bit vague on what I need to specify for `tools` since some appear without being listed).

How do I get the HoloViews box selection tool to synchronize multiple connected plots, so that selection in one, selects the corresponding values in the others?

---

I've read through the [documentation on "linked brushing"](http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Linked_Brushing.html) but can't get that to apply to the provided MWE even though that documentation states that linked brushing should (as expected) be "automatic", and "enabled for Bokeh plots sharing a common data source by simply adding a selection tool"